# iPhone Gmail Exchange Password Error

Tags: iphone, gmail, password, error, google-apps

I use an Exchange account to sync my Gmail account to the iPhone's mail app. Recently (the past 2 days or so), every time I try to open the account I get an error that says my password is incorrect. I've reentered the password several times with no luck; I've even verified the password by opening up gmail on my laptop, so I know the password is correct.

This problem was outlined on the [FeldThoughts](http://www.feld.com/wp/archives/2011/11/gmail-iphone-exchange-password-incorrect.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20FeldThoughts%20%28Feld%20Thoughts%29) blog, so I tried following his advice to [unlock the captcha in google apps](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/UnlockCaptcha?), but that didn't do anything either.

Is there anything else I can do?

**[Edit]** I'm not using 2 step authentication, and I'm using "Google Sync"/"Exchange", not imap or pop. [This page](http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740) explains how I set up Google sync.

Comment: are you using the imap or pop gmail setting?

Comment: Are you using two steps authentication?

Comment: @Gio no, not using 2 step authentication

Comment: Have you removed the account and re-added it?

Comment: @MattLove I tried doing that, no luck either. I eventually just installed the Gmail app for iPhone and used that.

Comment: Do you have a friend or relative with an iPhone that you could attempt setting up your account on their device? This would be a good way to isolate if it's something related to your device or if it's something on the Google server.

Comment: I think it was just something with the iPhone's mail app, but I'll try setting it up on a friend's phone.